# Using Resource-Files for Strings in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, resources, resx

I want to use a resource file for all my strings of my Xamarin app - since I want the same strings for all my 3 platforms (iOS, Android, UWP) I created a new resx file in the Xamarin-Forms project. But the file isn't handled as expected by Visual Studio ... the matching .cs file for the resources is not build. But is this necessary at all?

I tried several solutions:

```
var resourceLoader = new ResourceLoader();
label1.Text = resourceLoader.GetString("String1");
```

as well as

```
ResourceManager rm =
    new ResourceManager("MyApp.Resources1", typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
label1.Text = rm.GetString("String1");
```

But at runtime (UWP) I got the error:

```
Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.
```

And that should be only the first step - later I hope to bind the strings from the resources in XAML directly to the controls.

But I assume, I'm on a totally wrong way ... and there is no platform independent way to use string resources ... ?

Comment: There is a dedicated documentation on this topic https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/ did you check it?

Comment: Sure I did ... and I failed at the first step: Adding a RESX file to the project ... could only add "RESW" files ... sure, I can fix this by manual creating/adding the resx-file ... but then it missed the Designer.cs files ... thus I think there is something basically wrong in my assumptions.

Comment: I am using VS on Mac and I can create a RESX using the IDE. I guess you are using VS 201x on Windows? Can it be that you are trying to add a resource file on the UWP instead of Forms project?

Comment: Yes. VS2017 in Win10 latest Update. The Screenshots in the Tutorial are all from Mac what leaves me a little bit sceptically. Do you have a platform independing project? Directly on the Xamarin.IOS project I CAN add a resx file.

Comment: Here is another thread https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/98667/xamarin-froms-visual-studio-2017-string-localization

Comment: Nope ;-) Even tried to repair VS since the resx template doesn't appear in the NewItems list.

Comment: Seems like you are not alone: http://scottkdavis.com/posts/localizing-a-cross-platform-xamarin-application.html

Comment: Entire development system is designed by chimps for us monkeys ..

Answer (score 3):

You need to modify the Access Level on the Resources to Public

[image: Access Modifier]

Then you can just use

```
var s1 = Resource1.ResourceManager.GetString("String1");
```

anywhere in any project

Comment: The "Access Modifier" list box is disabled and empty.

Comment: Click on the resource.resx file and change the **Custom Tool** to **PublicResXFileCodeGenerator**

Answer (score 0):

[EvZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1970317/evz) points to the correct answer -
[Localizing Xamarin.Forms Apps with RESX Resource Files](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/)

I tested the Android sample project, and it crashed on Xamarin Live Player 1.2.80. However, the code worked fine on a physical Android device.

To add shared-RESX files, the project must be PCL or .NET Standard. SAP projects add only RESW files.